# predict sales using naive bayes and handle sparse data problem

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, prediction, naive-bayes, decision-theory

**Problem**
I am trying to use naive bayes for ranking products in a search application. I would like to predict the sales of a given product given the search keyword and the category. the current formula i have for the function (using naive bayes assumptions) is

P(product_sales/keyword_searched, product_category) = p(product_sales) * p(keyword_searched/product_sales) * p(product_category/product_sales)

where

p(product_sales) = num of times this product was sold / number of times this product was viewed
p(keyword_searched/product_sales) = num of times this product was sold after searching for this keyword/num of times this product was sold
p(product_category/product_sales) = num of times this product was sold for this category/num of times this product was sold

I have added smoothing as well.

**Questions**

1. I have a problem with data which is not significant. for eg. when a product is viewed only 20 times but sold 1 time get very high score compared to a product viewed 1 million times but sold only 200 times. One solution i can think of for this problem is to omit data when its not significant by setting a threshold. I would like to know is there a better way to handle this problem.
2. I selected naive bayes for its simplicity and decent accuracy. Is it a good choice for the problem stated above. If not what is a better choice ?